# Possibility of post processing of zabbix traps using scripts or configurations?

Tags: zabbix

I wish to know if its possible to post process traps and events that zabbix server would have received from zabbix agents  .  I am hoping there is some configuration which I don't know of .

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give more details, my assumption will be that you want to do something in case of a certain event. Most probably a trigger. Like a service went down or there are too many open connections. These can be handled by using zabbix's [Actions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/notifications/action) to intercept an event.

The following operation depends on what you have to do, it can be a remote command (executed  on remote agent) or a script executed by server.

The [remote command](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/notifications/action/operation/remote_command) is a straight forward concept working OOTB. Just follow the manual and howtos.

Running something on the server isn't there, but you can trick zabbix to do just that by using [custom alert scripts](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/notifications/media/script), which are just scripts launched by the server process. Then create a send message operation that uses your custom alert script and off you go.